# How to schedule a job to execute Python script in cloud to load data into bigquery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I am trying to setup a schedule job/process in cloud to load csv data into Bigquery from google buckets using a python script. I have manage to get hold off the python code to do this but not sure where do I need to save this code so that this task could be completed as an automated process rather than running the gsutil commands manualy.

Comment: What "cloud" are you trying to run your code in? Google Bigquery is only capable of holding data and running queries against it. It's not designed to run arbitrary code, there's regular Google Cloud for that.

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for quick reply, We are using google cloud platform. I am aware that the bigquery is only capable of holding data and it is not possible to configure any other code script into it. I just want to where should I save my python script file on google cloud platform and create a job to execute this script and how to configure this process.

Comment: this doesn't work for you? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reliable Task Scheduling on Google Compute Engine  |  Solutions  |  Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine), the 1st link in Google on "google cloud schedule a cron job", gives a high-level overview. [Scheduling Tasks With Cron for Python  |  App Engine standard environment for Python  |  Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron), the 2nd link, has step-by-step instructions. They boil down to:

- Create `cron.yaml` in the specificed format alongside your `app.yaml`
- optionally test it at a development server
- upload it to the Google Cloud with `appcfg.py update` or `update_cron`

Comment: I found that this solution works on top of the app setting.  Since I just created a script and I'm not very familiar with app development, I'm still working on how to setup that script on that app setting... or how to create the app from which I can call the scripts.  Does anyone have a reference on how to do that?  Thanks.