# How to get REST API information into my Google BigQuery SQL Table?

Tags: sql, rest, api, google-bigquery

What I am trying to achieve is this:
1. Access a REST API to download hotel reservation data - the data output format is in JSON
2. Convert JSON data into the correct format to be uploaded into SQL table
3. Upload this table of data onto Google BigQuery existing table as additional rows

Do let me know if any further information is required and if I have been clear enough

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain what is not working for you and what you tried so far. If you are looking for ways on how to upload information to BigQuery there is a lot of documentation about this so it's advisable that you review them and try and only if something si not working ask a question

Comment: I am new to this, so this is what I have done so far, I am able to run a python script on PowerBi to access data directly from the ReST API and then automatically convert this json file into table to create charts. 

I am migrating the data tables from PowerBi To BigQuery. So, right now, I don't know how can I create a schedule data import from the REST API to BigQuery.
I just need direction on the topics I can read to cover this because I have been all over the place in trying to get around with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [pretty good REST API tutorial](https://stackify.com/rest-api-tutorial/)

2) You can use a local SQL DB or use Cloud SQL. The process would be the same (Parse JSON and insert to DB)

If you decide to use Cloud SQL, you can parse the JSON and save it as a CSV then follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_the_csv_file)

or

simply parse the JSON and insert [using one of the following API's](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/apis)

3) Use can easily load data into any BigQuery table by [using BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/). You can also directly [insert the JSON data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json)

But as Tamir had mentioned, it would be best to ask questions if you encounter errors/issues. Since there are multiple ways to perform this type of scenario,  we cannot provide an exact solution for you.

Comment: 1. Thank you
3. If I want to schedule a call to the REST API every 3 hours, do I have to maintain a running on-premise server to download and save this CSV file locally, and then, using the BigQuery API, upload this file to BigQuery?
- Because my current solution is as follows, Write a python script on PowerBi to pull data from a REST API and then just schedule this script, which seems really simple as opposed to using BigQuery. Just that I can't use this going forward, as the data is too big.

Comment: You can use either scheduled cron jobs or cloud scheduler to perform this use case. Good explanation on Cloud Scheduler can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631352/how-to-make-requests-in-third-party-apis-and-load-the-results-periodically-on-go), Cron Jobs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40016694/how-to-schedule-a-job-to-execute-python-script-in-cloud-to-load-data-into-bigque). There is also an article that covers both [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/pitfalls-of-using-cron-jobs-with-google-app-engine-bf005f8bf7e6)

Comment: A final recommendation i can provide would be to use [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) Its a fully managed service used to schedule specific tasks and it has a BigQuery operator that can be used to load your data. This however will be more expensive than the above options.

Comment: Thanks alot. Will do this if all else fails